# I need to have an result of 36 to 47 from from an input of 0 to 127 - all using the same equation.

Tags: diophantine-equations

Using a formula, I need to have a result between 36 and 47 - depending on the input:

the input will be an integer between 0 and 127 as follows...

- 0, 12, 24, 36, etc MUST = 36
- 1, 13, 25, 37, etc MUST = 37;
- 2, 14, 26, 38, etc MUST = 38;
- 3, 15, 27, 39, etc MUST = 39;
- 4, 16, 28, 40, etc MUST = 40;
- 5, 17, 29, 41, etc MUST = 41;
- 6, 18, 30, 42, etc MUST = 42;
- 7, 19, 31, 43, etc MUST = 43;
- 8, 20, 32, 44, etc MUST = 44;
- 9, 21, 33, 45, etc MUST = 45;
- 10, 22, 34, 46, etc MUST = 46;
- 11, 23, 35, 47, etc MUST = 47.

What is the equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for an input $n$, take the remainder (residue) after reducing mod $12$, call that number $m$.  Then your equation is just $36+m$

Comment: That's awesome!!  Thanks. :)

Comment: No problem.  If this answered the question,  click the check mark next to the answer :).

Comment: @RyanAshton: Remember to give this guy credit for his effort!

Comment: Sorry - took me so long to get here.  Gave you credit.  Thanks. :)